# Trying to enable clean URLs: The clean URL test failed

Tags: 7, uri

I am trying to follow this [document](http://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls) to enable clean urls on a fresh Drupal installation. When I run the test, I get:

```
The clean URL test failed.
```

My host provider [confirms](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/94) that `mod_rewrite` is enabled. I am using a shared server.

In my Drupal installation folder, I see a hidden `.htaccess.txt` file. Apparently, it has been installed by Drupal itself.

But, I cannot find information in the document mentioned above explaining to solve this issue. What is missing to make Clean URLs work? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file name should just be `.htaccess`, without the `.txt` extension.

Answer (score 3):

Follow the link.Am guessing that you are using drupal 7.Check the reply by doncheks.
http://drupal.org/node/1572984#comment-6751806

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers.  Normally, link-only answers aren't considered good ones here.  You can keep the link, but you should really provide a summary.

Answer (score 2):

setting the correct RewriteBase inside files/default/setting.php fixes it for my virtual host (=typical with reseller hosting accounts):

```
  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
RewriteBase /~planet/v3
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I had a similar problem as you when I set up my first Drupal site. If you scroll down on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726439/clean-urls-not-working-in-drupal-7), I believe it was the same fix as the user 'alessandro oliviero' mentions. I had to change one line of the .htaccess file and I do believe it was the line with "RewriteRule" on it.